# Find all possible sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ such that $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Define
>   $$f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> a_n + \sin\pi x &\text{if}&x \in [2n, 2n + 1],\\
> b_n + \cos\pi x &\text{if}&x \in (2n − 1, 2n),
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   where $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. Find all possible sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ such that $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

**My Attempt :**

In order that $f$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, a necessary and sufficient condition is that 
$$\lim_{x\to(2n)^-} f(x)  =\lim_{x\to(2n)^+} f(x)  \text{ and }
\lim_{x\to(2n-1)^-}f(x)    =     \lim_{x\to(2n-1)^+} f(x)$$
as I have took
\begin{align}
a_1 + \sin2\pi   &= a_1\\
a_2 + \sin4\pi   &= a_2\\
\vdots&\\
a_n + \sin2n\pi  &= a_n
\end{align}
similarly
\begin{align}
b_1 + \cos \pi  &= b_1 + (-1)\\
b_2 + \cos3\pi  &= b_2 + (-1)\\
\vdots&\\
b_n + \cos(2n-1)\pi &= b_n + (-1)
\end{align}
so my answer  is that $a_1, a_2,\cdots,a_n$ and $b_1 + (-1), b_2 + (-1), \cdots ,b_n + (-1)$ are all possible sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ such that $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

is my answer is correct or not, I would be very  more thankful who will rectify my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$$f (2n^-)=b_n+\cos (2n\pi)=b_n+1$$

$$f (2n^+)=a_n+\sin (2n\pi)=a_n+0$$

thus $f $ is continuous at $[0,+\infty) $ if

$a_n=b_n+1$ for $n\ge 1$.
For example

$$b_n=\cos(2n) \;\;, \;\;a_n=2\cos^2 (n) $$

Comment: im not getting @Salahamam_ Fatima ....why u write  bn + cos(2nπ) ,,  i  think it will be bn + cos(2n-1)π

Comment: But what about an the odd points, that is, at $x=2n-1/2n+1$, we get $a_n=b_n-1$, isnt it?